# How can I track a scheduled notification in Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, notifications

Typically I'd schedule a push notification to be delivered sometime in the future like so -

```
Notification notification = new AppleNotification("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Happy birthday!\"}}");
var scheduled = await hub.ScheduleNotificationAsync(notification, new DateTime(2016, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0));
```

Here scheduled is of type [ScheduledNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.schedulednotification.aspx). How can I track whether or not my notification got delivered?

ScheduledNotification has a TrackingId, but I could not find any documentation on how to use it to get a [NotificationOutcome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.notifications.notificationoutcome.aspx) object.

Comment: Are there any advance regarding the issue?

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. It would seem that if exposed at all, this is exposed via the REST API

Comment: Gosh, 7 years passed, and this is still not possible... :facepalm: